# Can a GPlay account be authenticated with their GPGS id?

Tags: java, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-authentication

I'm currently working with a client-side application that's using Google Play Games Services to log in the user. We're then sending the user's google account id over to our Server, where they can log in to/restore an account using it.

The implementation on the client side is returning

```
GPGS client id: xxx-xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
GPGS auth code: 4/xxxxxxxx
message_salt: <ByteString@xxxxxx>
```

Using:

```
(GetServerAuthCodeResult) Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(mHelper.getApiClient(), getClientId())
```

However, [Google's server-side documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) requires an 'id token', which does not appear to be retrieved from the Games library.

Attempting to validate either the GPGS client id or GPGS auth code using either GoogleIdTokenVerifier, or through the standard web endpoint at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=TOKEN_HERE always yields an error return, containing;

```
{
 "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

Is there any way we can use the GPGS client id, or GPGS auth code to verify with Google that this is the legitimate account for the Google Play ID that the user is logging in with? Or do we need to completely change the implementation on the client-side?

Comment: Using the GPGS ID with Google APIs other than Google Play Games shouldn't work ([Android blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html)), so the `Invalid Value` error should be expected.

Comment: Yep, I figured that much out! I'm wondering if there's any way to verify the ownership of a user's account using their GPGS ID, rather than using the Google oauth API as posted above.